# qmake adds '-g' flag to compile under redhat 6

Tags: redhat, qmake

I have a bash script which compiles my program with or without symbols based on a flag.  It first makes the makefile with one of these commands

```
$QMAKE -makefile CONFIG-=release CONFIG+=debug $BASEDIR/project/myproj.pro
$QMAKE -makefile CONFIG-=debug CONFIG+=release $BASEDIR/project/myproj.pro
```

This works fine under Fedora, but under redhat 6 I notice the makefile always has the -g parameter added as a compiler option.  (regarless of which of the above commands I issue).  Under RH6 the latter line produces:

```
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE $(DEFINES)
```

while under Fedora 20 is produces:

```
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE $(DEFINES)
```

Can someone explain why qmake produces different Makefiles under the 2 versions of linux, and how to fix this?  (so that the latter command does not add the -g parameter for the compiler)

Comment: which `qmake` version are you using on either OS?

Comment: both are using qmake version 3.0